# ASP.NET MVC Deep Model Relationship? MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-relationship

Academic Example: Simple Tagging Mechanism - asp.net / MVC5

Models:

```
// post
public class Post
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<TagMap> TagMaps { get; set; } 
}

// tag
public class Tag
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
}

// tagmap
public class TagMap
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

The TagTable contains single tagwords (no duplicates). TagMap represents the relationship between the Post and (many) Tags.

I think this simple design should work or not? But I don't know how to setup the views for editing and creating the tags (not the tagmaps).

Any help would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are achieving a one-to-many relationship. (one post, many tags)..

You can have it with this..

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 TagId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TagMap
{
    public Int64 PostId { get; set; }
    public Int64 TagId { get; set; }

    [ForiegnKey("PostId")]
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
    [ForiegnKey("TagId")]
    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Take note that you do not need lazy loading on two tables since that you actually referenced it to tagmap table.

Answer (score 0):

Ok sounds nice.

I changed the model  to:

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IList<TagMap> TagMaps { get; set; }
}
```

In the index method of the postscontroller:

```
var posts = db.Posts.Include(m => m.TagMaps.Select(n => n.Tag));
```

And the view:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < item.TagMaps.Count; i++)
 {
   @Html.Raw(item.TagMaps[i].Tag.Name);
 }
```

This is working like a charme.